# Get rid of white background for excel export ssis

Tags: background, ssis, cells

[image: How to go from this:]

[image: To this:]

I need to make a report that export to excel, if got that. But the client wants to have the empty cells visible and not just a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the excel file you are exporting to go to the View Ribbon and tick the "Gridlines" in the show section. As far as I am concerned this is not an SSIS issue.

[image: how to enable gridlines]

If this box is ticked, tell us how you exporting to Excel: is it an ODBC or Excel Destination?